# Django Forms - ModelForms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am learning Django forms. When should I use `ModelForms` rather than `Forms`? Which is more suitable for production?

Comment: Wel `ModelForm`s are a special type of `Form`s that encapsulate saving the data into a corresponding model instance, etc.

Comment: yes, I understand that,  why should I use them instead of just form.form?

Comment: well if they correspond with a specific model, but there can be forms that perform some complex actions on multiple models for example.

Comment: But is that OK to use model forms in production?

Comment: What a strange question. Why shouldn't you use them in production? Why would Django have a part of its API that is not suitable for production?

Comment: Why don't you read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/.  You can use either forms or model forms , for example when you want to save data to a model  personally i use modelform , when i want to create for example a contact form i use forms.Form

Comment: The decision of using a tool is orthogonal to whether to use it in production. Why would you change the implementation of your application in production?

Comment: @Dimitris Kougioumtzis, I already did it countless time and yet it doesn't sink in.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, that is not what I meant, you went beyond my question there

Answer (score 3):

> I am kinda lost, so, why should I used modelforms instead of using just forms

Conceptually, `ModelForm`-derived form classes aim to replicate the underlying model's behavior as closely as possible. I use 'behavior' here in a general sense to mean: a) model fields (i.e., data); and b) model constraints (i.e., everything else, which might include model field validators or custom business logic or anything else).

From an implementation standpoint, `ModelForm` has a similar initial basis to `Form`.

However unlike `Form`, `ModelForm` allows tight `Model` instance integration.

`ModelForm` also allows:

- One-to-one field type mapping between your form fields and the model's fields.  Conversely, if you used `Form` rather than `ModelForm`, you'd need to  re-declare any model fields in your `Form` class. This would mean that you would duplicate application logic. To illustrate this point, see the below from the [official Django `ModelForm` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example)):

```
    ### models.py

    from django.db import models


    class Book(models.Model):
        """
        Sample book model.
        """
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)


    ### forms.py

    from django import forms


    class BookForm(forms.Form):
        """
        Your `forms.Form` subclass loosely representing the `Book` model.
        """
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        authors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all())


    # Alternatively,


    class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
        """
        Your `forms.ModelForm` subclass representing the `Book` model directly.
        """
        class Meta:
            model = Book
            fields = ['name', 'authors']
```

- model fields to be [included or explicitly excluded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) from the resulting form
- [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) to be created just as easily.

> which one is more suitable for production

Both kinds of forms may fit most setups. Both `ModelForm` and `Form` are native Django web framework components. Your choice of whether to use `ModelForm` or `Form` will depend on the specific project's requirements, as well as personal preferences and adopted code conventions.

In summary, if a model can be represented easily by using a `ModelForm` instance, use `ModelForm`. If not, use a customized `Form`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have in your application a model  for example Book  with a field title

models.py

```
Class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()
```

To represent it in a form you have two options

forms.py

```
from myapp.models import Book

class BookSimpleForm(forms.Form):
  title = forms.CharField()
```

or

```
 class BookModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = Book
          fields = ('title',)
```

When you use to save the data of the form in the simple Form you have to write the code of the save method because Form isn't attached to a model. When you use a modelForm because in the class Meta you specific tell the form when it runs the save method  , save the posted data to the model of the instance of the modelform.

in views.py

```
from app.models import Book
from app.forms import BookSimpleForm, BookModelForm
```

First  option

```
 def method(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
     book = Book(request.POST)
     book.save()
```

Second option

```
   def method(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
      form = BookModelForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

In the first method  request.Post has the posted data (title) so you create an instance of a book and save it . ModelForm has method save so as to save the posted data via the modeform save method and to validate them